# correct output but online judge won't except

Tags: c

**question:**
You are given a following process.

There is a platform with n columns. 1×1 squares are appearing one after another in some columns on this platform. If there are no squares in the column, a square will occupy the bottom row. Otherwise a square will appear at the top of the highest square of this column.

When all of the n columns have at least one square in them, the bottom row is being removed. You will receive 1 point for this, and all the squares left will fall down one row.

You task is to calculate the amount of points you will receive.

**input:**
The first line of input contain 2 integer numbers n and m (1≤n,m≤1000) — the length of the platform and the number of the squares.

The next line contain m integer numbers c1,c2,…,cm (1≤ci≤n) — column in which i-th square will appear.

**output:**
Print one integer — the amount of points you will receive.

**example:**
input:
3 9 
1 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 3
output:
2

**problem i'm having:**
I have alrady tried the example and few other input, and got the correct output but when I paste my code to the online judge
it tells me `Runtime error on test one`
**note**
I'm new to programming so, sorry if this is actually a simple problem which i could just search it up. I did search and work on it for an hour but I just couldn't find the reason for this error.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// use fgets, strtok , sscanf
int main ()
{
    int length,blocks,holder=0;
    scanf("%d %d",&length,&blocks);
    int x[length];
    int c[length];
    char str2[blocks*2];
    getchar();
    
    fgets(str2, blocks*2 , stdin);

    char* piece = strtok(str2, " ");

    for(int i=0; piece != NULL ; i++)
    {
        sscanf(piece, "%d" , &x[i]);
        piece = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    //to input each block to the platform
    for(int u=0; u<length ; u++)
    {
        holder=0;
        for(int k=0; k<blocks ; k++)
        {
            if(x[k]==u+1)
            {
                holder++;
            }
        }
        c[u] = 0;
        c[u] += holder;
    }
    int smallest=c[0];
    for(int i=1 ; i<length ; i++)
    {
        if(smallest>c[i])
        {
            smallest= c[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",smallest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221603/discussion-on-question-by-ms01-correct-output-but-online-judge-wont-except).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*when I paste my code to the online judge it tells me Runtime error on test one*

Using your inputs, with the exact code you posted, I also see a run-time error, i.e. *array index out of range*

To address this problem required seeing that the [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) variable `int x[length]` was being created in-correctly for its intended purpose.

The two areas I made changes to:

- The variable `x` should be defined with `blocks` elements, not `length` elements in order to survive the loop that populates it later.  This change is essential, and without it result in the *array index out of range* errors.
- The loop itself, although potentially viable, was re-written into what I believe is a more idiomatic construct.

There may be other problems in your code, but by making the changes described above in your code, and running your example input:
`3 9`
`1 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 3`
The result `2` was obtained:

Change areas are commented

```
int main ()
{
    int length,blocks,holder=0;
    scanf("%d %d",&length,&blocks);
    int x[blocks];//change to contain 'blocks' elements
    int c[length];
    //char str2[blocks*2];//too small for eg `1 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 3`
    //                                        |||||||||||||||||+NULL == 18 bytes
    char str2[80] = {0}// needs 18 minimum, but memory is cheap
    getchar();
    
    fgets(str2, blocks*2 , stdin);
    // Changed loop construct slightly here
    int i = 0;
    char* piece = strtok(str2, " ");
    while(piece)
    {
        x[i] = atoi(piece);
        i++;
        piece = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    //to input each block to the platform
    for(int u=0; u<length ; u++)
    {
        holder=0;
        for(int k=0; k<blocks ; k++)
        {
            if(x[k]==u+1)
            {
                holder++;
            }
        }
        c[u] = 0;
        c[u] += holder;
    }
    int smallest=c[0];
    for(int i=1 ; i<length ; i++)
    {
        if(smallest>c[i])
        {
            smallest= c[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",smallest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked the runtime error had disappear once again thank you very much sir.